# Range of Fourier Transform on $L^1$

Tags: fourier-transform

I have a function $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$. Its Fourier tranfsorm is uniformly continuous and goes to zero at infinity. I know, in addition, that if I assume that $xf(x)$ is integrable, then the Fourier transform is continuously differentiable. My question is: there are weaker assumptions under which one can claim that the Fourier transform is just in $W^{1,1}$ (at least on bounded intervals)?

Comment: Can you make the question more precise? What kind of criteria are you interested in?

Comment: I would like to know if there exist (in the literature) sufficient conditions on functions $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ that guarantee that the Fourier transform of $f$ is a function in $W_{loc}^{1,1}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Yes, many such criteria exist, for instance $f$ being a Schwartz function will do.

Comment: I agree, but the assumption of being a Shwartz function is a very "strong" assumption (even stronger than "xf(x) integrable") and entails much more that $W^{1,1}$-regularity for the Fourier transform, since it is an isometry on the set of the Schwartz functions.
I was rather interested in some kind of "minimal" criterium. Precisely, since I already know that assuming "$xf(x)$ integrable" entails that the Fourier transform is $C^1$, I wondered if there were weaker assumptions under which the Fourier transform would be just $W^{1,1}$.